# Dynamic DataTemplate switching

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-2.0

I am trying to achieve the same behavior as indicated in the following post.  The trouble is this post solves the problem for WPF.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/4fd42590-8375-46d0-b7bc-6c217df0f0ba/

Any ideas on how to do this in Silverlight 2.0?

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait for DynamicResources to be supported in a future version.  If you need to do it once (e.g. at load time), the the Silverlight Toolkit's ImplicitStyleManager is a good solution (http://silverlight.codeplex.com)...otherwise you'll have to wait.  WPF is more feature rich than SL2.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I will look into it.

We are currently using some of the controls provided by ComponentOne, and they implemented a DataTemplateSelector (similar to the WPF implementation) for their ItemsControl.

That is the approach I am using currently, but there are still some issues I am working through.

Thanks Again.